# Why my components are Rerender and how can I prevent this?

Tags: react-native

I have a list of users. When I longpress a Modal is opening. While I longpress, I dispatch an userID.

So the modal is open, the user id is set. It works fast.

But if I add useSelector in my app, and I want to again open my modal, then its slow/ a little delay and my react.memo component is rerender. How can I prevent this ?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Pressable, Image, Dimensions, Animated } from 'react-native';
import BottomSheet, { BottomSheetFlatList } from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet';
import { chatMockFlat } from '../utils/mockChat';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { ChatPeopleSetting } from '../components/modal/chat/chatPeopleSetting';
import { Portal } from 'react-native-portalize';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { setCurrentUserID } from '../redux/slice/chat/chatSlice';

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

const chatSearchValue = state => state.chatSlice.headerSearchChats;
const currentUserID = state => state.chatSlice.currentUserID;


const Item = React.memo(({ name, date, image, id, text, modal }) => {
  console.log('rerender')
  return (
    <Pressable style={s.chatItem}>

      <View style={s.viewLeftImage}>
        <Pressable delayLongPress={100} onLongPress={() => modal(id)} style={s.imagePress}>
          <Image source={{uri: image}} style={s.profile_image} resizeMode='contain' />
          <View style={s.onlineStatus}></View>
        </Pressable>
      </View>

      <View style={s.viewMidText}>
        <View style={s.viewHeaderText}>
          <Text style={s.name}>{name}</Text>
          <Text style={s.date}>{date}</Text>
        </View>
        <Text style={s.text}>{text}</Text>
      </View>

    </Pressable>
  )
});

const Messages = (props) => {
  const modals = Array.from({ length: 8 }).map(_ => React.useRef(null).current);
  const userID = useSelector(currentUserID);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const bottomSheetRef = React.useRef(null);

  const handleOpenModalSetting = React.useCallback((e) => {
    modals[1]?.open();
    dispatch(setCurrentUserID(e));
  });

  const handleCloseModal = React.useCallback(() => modals[1].close()
  // variables
  const snapPoints = React.useMemo(() => ['25%', '100%'], []);

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <Item name={item.name} date={item.date} image={item.image} id={item.id} text={item.text} />
  )

  return (
    <View style={s.container}>
      <BottomSheet
        ref={bottomSheetRef}
        index={1}
        style={s.sheetContainer}
        snapPoints={snapPoints}
        handleStyle={{borderTopLeftRadius: 16, borderTopRightRadius: 16,}}
      >
        <BottomSheetFlatList
          data={chatMockFlat}
          keyExtractor={i => i.id}
          renderItem={renderItem}
        >

        </BottomSheetFlatList>
      </BottomSheet>
      <Portal>
          <ChatPeopleSetting ref={el => (modals[1] = el)} onPressExit={handleCloseModal} />
        </Portal>
    </View>
  )
};
```

Modals constant console log first click

```
Array [
  null,
  Object {
    "close": [Function close],
    "open": [Function open],
  },
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
]
```

second click (when its not opening)

```
Array [
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the bottom instructions and fix reasons causing re-rendering your component:

- Add **shallowEqual** as second argument to **useSelector**
- Add dependencies as second argument to **handleOpenModalSetting** and **handleCloseModal** functions. (if you want generally the functions don't be re-render just set empty array)

***Update:***

Update following code pieces into your code and try once.

```js
//Imported packages
import {shallowEqual} from 'react-redux'

...
const userID = useSelector(currentUserID, shallowEqual);
...
const handleOpenModalSetting = React.useCallback((e) => {
  modals[1]?.open();
  dispatch(setCurrentUserID(e));
}, [modals, dispatch])
...
const handleCloseModal = React.useCallback(() => { 
  modals[1].close();
}, [modals]);
...
```

Comment: Thanks but now my modal is not opening anymore. Its opening but only once. Why? I editet my post with a console. log statement from my modal. If I remove useSelector then I can opening my modal as often as I can, but if I use useSelector then I only can one open my modal

Comment: I did edit answer, pay attention to update section

Comment: it does not work. I can again only once open modal. If I close and click again nothing happens. It works when the useselector isnt there. But it has to there... Maybe in every rerender when the changed is done because I use dispatch so set the userid then my modals are recreating I think. Because its happen when its rerender